# Use Powershell to split one column of an excel workbook by a delimiter

Tags: powershell

Hello all I am still trying to learn power shell. the issue I have is that I am trying to use Power shell to look at one column in a workbook and split it into several columns by a delimiter (=) horizontally 3 times. I have also looked into using the split option but I do not understand exactly how to do either. I can not post the either sheet but the line is
Hash_tag

[image]

This is what I would like to see

[image]

The below is that I have

```
$SRReport="C:\Users\ddpierce\Desktop\Metrics\u_service_request.csv"
$OBJExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$OBJexcel.visible=$true
$WorkBook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($SRReport)
$worksheets=$workbook.worksheets
$sheet=$worksheets.item(1)
$sheet.activate
$range=$sheet.usedrange
$a = $countrange
$colA=$sheet.range("A1").EntireColumn
$colrange=$sheet.range("A1")
$xlDelimited = 1
$xlTextQualifier = -4142
$xlTextFormat = 1
$xlConsecutiveDelimiter = $true
$xlTab = $flase
$xlSemicolon = $true
$xlComma = $true
$xlSpace = $true                
$xlOther = $flase
$xlOtherChar = $true,':'
#Convert Text To Columns
#$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$true,$false,$false,$false,$false)# = nothing 1
#$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$false,$true,$false,$false,$false)# = nothing 2
#$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$false,$false,$true,$false,$false)# = split on simi 3
#$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$false,$false,$false,$true,$false)# = split on comma 4
#$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$false,$false,$false,$false,$true)# = split on space 5
#$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$true,$true,$true,$true,$true,$true,$true)
$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$xlConsecutiveDelimiter,$xlTab,$xlSemicolon,$xlComma,$xlSpace,$xlOther,$xlOtherChar)
#$sheet.columns.autofit()
#Save as XLSX
#$workbook.saveas("C:\Users\ddpierce\Desktop\Metrics\u_service_request2.csv")
#$WorkBook.save=$true
#$workbook.close($true)
#$objExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: Why not use `Import-Csv` and split the column in the objects returned. Then `Export-Csv` the new data and open that in Excel. Much, MUCH simpler that way.

Comment: If only it were that easy. There are other columns that have various data, and I can not split those.  Basically this is taking several reports and combining it into one. I had all that working until now them wanting to have the last cloumn with 3 datasets split by space and = like Info=1 Info=2 Info=3 would be split into six columns by the space and = sign

Comment: I figured out that 3-5 the 5 true/false statements after $colA.texttocolumns switches semicolon, comma, and space respectively but the = sign is throwing me as an "other" delimiter

Comment: You should edit your question and post a sample of the input file **and also** an example of the desired output. Without knowing exactly what to split into what, it's a bit of a guessing game..

Comment: Is that better? As I said before I figured out which true/false statements represent semicolon, comma, and space. As well as gotten the "other" character of = working with the above code. But the "other" character  wants to overwrite the next cell rather than everything moving over like it does when you do it in excel